# Array of drop down list in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to change the value of dropdown dinamically.
here the case:
for example i have an array of dropdown and has 2 names on it, like name1 and name2,
the name 1 has grade and also the name2.

what i want to do is change the first dropdown which has the value of name and
i want the second dropdown change automatically according to his grade.
Like:
John -> 90
Paul -> 80

please help me to find the index of array and the selected value of dropdown using javascript. thanks in advance.

```
<script>
function Change2(a){
var options1= document.getElementById('stuname[]').options;
var options2= document.getElementById('stugrade[]').options;

    for(i = 0; options1.length;i++){
        if(options1[i].selected == true){
            options2[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
} // what I want is, if I change the first dropdown in row 1, the 2nd dropdown should change too, and same in row 2.
</script>

<?php
$getlist= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM STUDENTS");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getlist)){

        print "<select id = 'stuname[]' name = 'stuname[]' class = 'text4' onchange = 'Change2(this.value);'>";
            $getname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM NAME");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getname)){
                $name = $row['name'];   
                print "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>";
            }
        print "</select>";

        print"<select id = 'stugrade[]' name = 'stugrade[]' onchange = 'Change2(this.value);'>";?>
<?php
        $getgrade = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GRADE");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getgrade)){
            $grade = $row['grade']; 
            print "<option value = '$grade'>$grade</option>";
        }
        print "</select><br>";
    }

?> // heres my code.. edited
```

Comment: Where is the Change2 function defined? Or are you asking us to define it?

Comment: And if this should be done in JavaScript why are you showing the PHP script that generates the page, rather than the HTML as seen in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common approach to solve this kind of issues, differently you need change querys and names accordingly

**JS file**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getfirstSelect();
    })
    function getSecondSelect() {
        var firstDropDownSelectedID = $('#firstSelect option:selected').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getSecondDropDownOptions.php",
            data: "firstDropDownSelectedID="+firstDropDownSelectedID
        }).done(function (result) {
            //alert(result)
            $("#secondSeect").html(result);
        });
    }
    function getfirstSelect() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getFirstDropDownOptions.php",
            data: {}
        }).done(function (result) {
            //alert(result)
            $("#secondSeect").html(result);
        });
    }
```

**getSecondDropDownOptions.php**

```
<?
$firstDropDownSelectedID = isset($_POST['firstDropDownSelectedID']) ? (int)$_POST['firstDropDownSelectedID'] : 0;
$list2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM LIST2 WHERE relatedid=".$firstDropDownSelectedID);
$returnString = "";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($list2)){
                $returnString.= "<option value = '".$row['grade']."' >".$row['grade']."</option>";
        }
print $returnString;
?>
```

**getFirstDropDownOptions.php**

```
<?

$list1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM LIST1 ");
$returnString = "";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($list1)){
                $returnString.= "<option value = '".$row['grade']."' >".$row['grade']."</option>";
        }
print $returnString;
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="formName">
<select name="firstSelect" id="firstSelect" onchange="updateSecondSelect()"></select>
<select name="secondSeect id="secondSeect" ></select>
</form>
```

Comment: on the code above it works fine in the first row, when I try to select the name it change the grade also but only in first row. and when i try to change the name in the 2nd row it wont work for the grade of 2nd row.

Comment: like: name[0][0] works fine but in name[0][1]..name[0][2] it doesnt work. i want to know on how to get the column and rows of select. thanks

Comment: hi. it was a small bug, in a php files in an options, please, delete selected. I updated my answer, hope this will help+